# Overlapping DIVs in CSS

Tags: html, css

I know this has been asked before on this site, and I have looked at all the answers. However, I still can't find a solution to mine.

When I resize my browser, all my divs (which will be buttons later) go over each other.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: beige;
}

#Rosa {
  color: White;
  font-family: Arial Black;
  max-width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 90%;
  top: 1.5%;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#Martin {
  color: White;
  font-family: Arial Black;
  max-width: 147px;
  height: 25px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: fixed;
  left: 77%;
  top: 1.5%;
  padding: 2px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#Malcom {
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial Black;
  max-width: 87px;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 2px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: fixed;
  left: 68.5%;
  top: 1.5%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#Design {
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial Black;
  width: 60px;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 2px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: fixed;
  left: 62%;
  top: 1.5%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navigation a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

#Bar {
  min-width: 100%;
  max-height: 260px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <div id="Rosa"> Rosa Parks </div>
  <div id="Martin">Martin Luther Jr.</div>
  <div id="Malcom">Maclom X</div>
  <div id="Design">Design</div>

  <img id="Bar" src=./assets/bar.png>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

P.s. this is a navigation bar which stays at the top of the page even when you scroll.

Comment: please post html too. Have you looked into flexbox?

Comment: Posted image doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something similar to this. That will keep the menu to the right or left depending on what float you choose and it won't go over each other when the window gets smaller.

```css
.navigation {
width: 100%;
height: 260px;
background-color: black;

}

.menu {
display: inline-block;
color: white;
float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="menu" id="Rosa"> Rosa Parks </div>
  <div class="menu" id="Martin">Martin Luther Jr.</div>
  <div class="menu" id="Malcom">Maclom X</div>
  <div class="menu" id="Design">Design</div>

  
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this, but it still goes behind each other. (I also removed my bar which I added)
Should I remove the `position: fixed` from my ID's?

Comment: Yes. The fixed is what makes them go over each other

Comment: If I remove the `position: fixed` then all the text goes to the top right of the screen without any space between them

Comment: I fixed it with margin! Thank you so much! I really really appreciate it :DDD

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modern approach using `flexbox`. Some will say to use an unordered list in the `<nav>` instead of links, tomayto tomahto.

[Scotch](https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties) has a great write up on how to use `flexbox` and you can view the [support on Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(129, 123, 123, 0.5);
}

main {
  padding-top: 50px; /* should match <header> height so <header> doesn't hide content */
  min-height: 1500px;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 1rem;
}

.primary {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.primary > a {
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <img class="logo" src="http://placehold.it/50x50/A10">
  
  <nav class="primary flex">
    <a href="#rosa-parks">Rosa Parks</a>
    <a href="#mlk">Martin Luther Jr.</a>
    <a href="#malcom-x">Maclom X</a>
    <a href="#design">Design</a>
  </nav>
  
</header>

<main>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor.
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor.
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor.
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor.
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor.
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor.
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor.
  </p>
  
</main>
```

Not sure how you intended to use the `<img>` but I used it like a logo.

Comment: Are you talking about the code snippet? If so, it's a StackOverflow feature that lets us create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in our questions and answers.  FWIW, Brackets is a code editor for HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the div's are going into each other is because you're using `position: fixed` and `left` in all divs that have id's (which is not a good practice too).

Remove these `position: fixed` and `left`s and it should work properly.

Comment: If I remove `position: fixed` the text goes behind my black bar. If I remove both `position: fixed` and `left` then it resets to top left

Comment: @ImperfectLion **Robson** is correct, using `absolute` or `fixed` positioning for page layout is a bad idea, mostly because it's not conducive to responsive web design and in general a giant headache.

Comment: Text goes behind bar because you've set that as z-index:1. If you want it behind it's meant to be -1

Comment: @hungerstar So should I use `relative`?

Comment: @ImperfectLion I would use a different approach. Working on answer meow.

Comment: @hungerstar I know this is probably frustrating explaining to a noob. But I want the black bar and the text to stay on top of the page while I scroll through it (because it is the navigation bar).
Here's a pic: http://imgur.com/a/9uCwS

Answer (score 0):

use `float: left` instead of `position: fixed;` and `left: Ypx;` for your divs inside `.navigation`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting a position try setting `display: inline-block`. Also, if there are settings such as this applied to multiple images you should place them in a class style. That way you do not have to edit multiple styles each time you want to make a change.

You should also remove position, top, left, z-index from ALL styles.